# Change the Swipe direction of View Pager android

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager

I have a `gridview` which displays thumbnail images from sdcard. If I click on one thumbnail image it displays the fullscreenImage using `ImageView`. I have used `viewPager` to swipe inside the `imageview`. Swipe is working fine, but swipe is not according to the standards. Means if I swipe from Left to Right, I should be able to go to recent photo, but it is vice-verse i.e if I swipe image from Right to Left it goes to the recent image.

How can change the direction of swipe inside the `imageView`?

```
 int position = i1.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

Here I'm getting the position of the thumbnail image from gridview. Then setting to the currentItem.

```
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(this, imagePaths);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: please share sample code here

Comment: Please let me known if you required more code.

Answer (score 0):

Set your current position at last or first based on your direction.

Comment: int position = i1.getExtras().getInt("id");     pager.setCurrentItem(position);   Do I have to set in these?

Comment: s if you want to swipe from left to right set the last fragment as first.

Comment: Can I provide an example?